# Consider a web page of width 1000px. What is the exact horizontal ( from left ) position of the div with id="inner_div" element

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone hope you are fine.

I gave a test and I got this question wrong.

**Consider a web page of width 1000px. What is the exact horizontal ( from left ) position of the div with id="inner_div" element?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Div elements</title>
      <style>
         #first_div{
         width:500px;
         float:right;
         }
         #second_div{
         width:500px;
         float:right;
         }
         #inner_div{
         width:100px;
         float:right;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="first_div">
         First div element
      </div>
      <div id="second_div">
         <div id="inner_div">
            Find my exact location.
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

According to me the answer should be **500px to 600px** if you can verify that or correct me it would be a great help.

Comment: It will be 400px

Comment: yes as @RinkeshGolwala said it would be 400px because 1st and 2nd div occupy 500px each. and the 3rd div is inside 2nd div and occupies 100px so 500-100 = 400px;

Comment: Thank you I got it.

Answer (score 2):

You should try it yourself in notepad.

2 float divs will be side by side.
and inner_div will be right aligned to the second_div.
so from left it is 500px-100px=400px away.

Comment: `div`s are block-level elements. They will not flow side by side but take a new line unless there display property is changed

Comment: "divs are block-level element" is correct. But the float property will try to align it right until the width is available.

Answer (score 1):

the first div floats right and takes up space from 501 to 1000.  The second div floats right and goes to the next line.  this also takes up 501 to 1000.  The inner div is inside the the second div. it floats right and takes up 901 to 1000